# How can I drop corrupt event in Flume-NG?

Tags: flume

I am using flume file channel with avro source-sink topology to transfer logs. Along with the logs, flume is also resulting into a lot of corrupt logs. How can I drop such logs.

Corruption is basically happening due to merging of some logs. Lets say I have 10 logs coming from machine A and 10 logs coming from machine B. What is happening is that Flume is giving me 21 logs (10 each from machine A and B) and 1 log which is a combination of a log from machine A and B. However this is not that frequent. I am getting around 1 corrupt log in 10000 logs but due to scale this also is turning out to be a problem.

Comment: What do you mean by corrupt?

Comment: I am getting some logs which are basically a combination of some 2 other logs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [interceptor](http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#flume-interceptors) to discard the events of your choice. May be you can introspect the body of the event to check for corruption and discard those.

Comment: Could you please explain how can I introspect the body on the fly since the merging of logs is happening randomly and I don't really have a fixed pattern to check for.